# Cumulative price calculations in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, cumulative-sum

I have a dataset of price points per different names and I want to create in PowerBi the cumulative total price **for each row for each name**.

I 've tried creating a measure that calculates the sum of "level price" but **I can't make it work for each name separately.**

***This is my table:***

| id | name | lower | upper | unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AA1 | 0 | 0 | $ - |
| 1 | AA1 | 0 | 10,000 | $ 5 |
| 2 | AA1 | 10,000 | 50,000 | $ 4 |
| 3 | AA1 | 50,000 | 10,000 | $ 3 |
| 0 | AB1 | 0 | 0 | $ - |
| 1 | AB1 | 0 | 100,000 | $ 10 |
| 2 | AB1 | 100,000 | 250,000 | $ 9 |
| 3 | AB1 | 250,000 | 500,000 | $ 8 |
| 0 | AC1 | 0 | 0 | $ - |
| 1 | AC1 | 0 | 10,000 | $ 6 |
| 2 | AC1 | 10,000 | 50,000 | $ 5 |
| 3 | AC1 | 50,000 | 100,000 | $ 4 |

For example, if we want to calculate total price for each upper level of "AA1", we would have:

- for id=0 price would be zero (0*0)
- for id=1 price would be (10.000-0)*5 = 50.000$
- For id=2 price would be 50.000(price of id=1) + (50.000-10.000)*4 = 50.000+40.000*4=210.000

**and so on until we reach id=3 and then we start over because we have a new name**(each name might have 1,5,6,10 ids or more)

In order to achieve the above results I created in Power BI two helper columns when I imported the dataset:

1. **size** -> it is the difference of upper - lower quantities
2. **level_price** -> is each name's price per id

Any ideas what would be the simplest way to write this? Once this achieved I would be able to filter in the dashboard view "AA1" And see a table with all levels of AA1 only and final price per upper limit.

**Expected Outcome:**

| id | name | lower | upper | unit | size (upper-lower) | level_price (unit*size) | total_price (this is the desired outcome fromBI) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AA1 | 0 | 0 | $ - | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | AA1 | 0 | 10,000 | $ 5 | 10,000 | $50,000 | $50,000 |
| 2 | AA1 | 10,000 | 50,000 | $ 4 | 40,000 | $160,000 | $210,000 |
| 3 | AA1 | 50,000 | 100,000 | $ 3 | 50,000 | $150,000 | $360,000 |
| 0 | AB1 | 0 | 0 | $ - | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | AB1 | 0 | 100,000 | $ 10 | 100,000 | $1,000,000 | $1,000,000 |
| 2 | AB1 | 100,000 | 250,000 | $ 9 | 150,000 | $1,350,000 | $2,350,000 |
| 3 | AB1 | 250,000 | 500,000 | $ 8 | 250,000 | $2,000,000 | $4,350,000 |
| 0 | AC1 | 0 | 0 | $ - | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | AC1 | 0 | 10,000 | $ 6 | 10,000 | $60,000 | $60,000 |
| 2 | AC1 | 10,000 | 50,000 | $ 5 | 40,000 | $200,000 | $260,000 |
| 3 | AC1 | 50,000 | 100,000 | $ 4 | 50,000 | $200,000 | $460,000 |

Next steps would be to be able to calculate the price for any requested quantity, but this is a long shot since I am struggling with simple steps yet!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: thank you for the notice. I will fix the post. @DavidMakogon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a calculated column like this one:

```
total_price = 
  var curId = [id]
  var curName = [name]
  RETURN CALCULATE(SUM([level_price]), ALL('YourTable'), 'YourTable'[name] = curName && 'YourTable'[id] <= curId)
```

Additional - based on your ask in the comments:

```
total_price = 
  var curId = [id]
  var curName = [name]

  var result = SWITCH([type],
    "cumulative",
       CALCULATE(SUM([level_price]), ALL('YourTable'), 'YourTable'[name] = curName && 'YourTable'[id] <= curId),

    "standard",
       [size] * [unit],

    "tier",
       [upper size] * [unit]
   )

  RETURN result
```

Comment: thank you that looks good so far. This seems very helpful. 
can it work with an if statement? for example 
if type = X then (your calculated column) 
if type = Y then (a fixed price)
if type = Z then (here instead of having this cumulative logic - I would write it as qnt*unit)

Comment: Sure it is possible, perhaps use `SWITCH` over `IF`. Are needing the conditional for the same result of the Calculated Column or would a Measure be more suited?

Comment: I have 3 price types. 
once type is "cumulative" I want your calculated results.
if type = standard then the calculation should be unit * size (e.g type =standard, size =10, unit =2, then total_price = 20)
if type = tier then total_price = upper*unit

is this helpful? 

How can I do that and still be sure that I am calculating prices of the same "name" and I am not picking wrong rows?

Comment: Updated answer above with the `SWITCH` statement based on `[type]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answers were spot on! I've played around with multiple options and Or statements in that switch statement and it works fine. 

last question and I should probably have to open new issue: can I set an input field like I would do with a python script? 

Goal: I will select a name and manually put in a block/cell : size = 50 (or whatever) 
and if the type = cumulative it will give me the total price (based on the same cumulative logic) if fixed: 50*unit...etc